# Azure Terraform The app "xxx" used for the app service needs to be globally unique

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I hope somebody can shade some light on this issue which is weird.

I have an azure infra scripted in terraform to deploy 2 web apps, which I am gonna call them:

- webapp1
- webapp2

A couple of days ago I deployed them to azure using terraform, and storing the tfstate in a container

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "xx-xx-terraform"
    storage_account_name = "xxx"
    container_name       = "xxx"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

This was working just fine. Today I needed to run some updates which required to destroy the web application and deployed them once again. But as I have many other resources in this script. I run the command:

```
terraform destroy -target azurerm_app_service-webapp1
terraform destroy -target azurerm_app_service-webapp2
```

This destroyed the webapps and removed them from my tfstate.

So I tried to run a `terraform apply` but suddenly I started getting this error:

```
The name "webapp1" used for the App Service needs to be globally unique and isn't available: Site names only allow alphanumeric characters and hyphens, cannot start or end in a hyphen, and must be less than 64 chars.
```

This error occures for both webapps. So I checked once again my backend state, and the apps are not there, which is good. So I thought that maybe somebody else used that name while my terraform was destroying. I used the portal to create the web app with the same exact name, and the name was available to use.

I really don't understand why Terraform thinks that the web app name exists.

Did this issue ever occurred to anyone and how a way how to solve it?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide. And please if you need more info just let me know

Comment: Where in the Terraform flow did that error occur? Is it during validation (config), plan (provider), or apply (API) error?

Comment: During the apply. If I do the validate and plan everything is fine because I see that terraform reconize that has to create 2 resources, and when I do the apply, it throws the error

Comment: That would make it an Azure API issue, and you may need to open a support case with them.

Comment: I thought the same. For now I solved my issue in a savage way. I created the resource manually, and imported it back to terraform. My assumption is that  I don't let pass enough time between the destroy and apply not giving enough time to azure to refresh. But this is just an assumption. As you said is better if I open a ticket and ask more clarification from the support team. Thank you so much for your time